# SSR error when Writing API in Nuxt with Router Module?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt with Router Module
Currently, i write api like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="row flex">
    {{posts.id}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Item from '~/components/feeds/Post.vue'
  export default {
    async asyncData ({ store, route }) {
      let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/feeds/' + route.params.id + '/')
      return {
        posts: data
      }
    },
    components: {
      'post-detail': Item
    }
  }
</script>
```

I get this error:
[image]
How can I fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can somehow help you.

```
export default {
        layout: 'main',
        async asyncData ({store, params}) {
            let projectId = params.id;
            let {data} = await axios.get('https://admin.xxx.com/page/preview/' + projectId)
            return {
                pageContent: data.xxx,
                title: data.xxx.meta_title,
                description: data.xxx.meta_desc,
                keywords: data.xxx.meta_key,

            }
        },
}
```

Comment: then maybe it should be a comment